# PHP: Creating something like one unique file for each job post display

Tags: php, sql, post, hyperlink

in my new project, I want to build a job portal. I've got my database connected and things are going well but how can I create something like a file for each single job post? I know that I should build a basic file which holds every single SQL data, but what if someone wants to share a specific link of one job if it all runs from one file and just grabs the needed information from the session? **how does it work with the link so that i got one file that grabs the information to put in from the link?**

I'm quite new to PHP so it would be great if someone could help me, thanks

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: You should create a general file that fetches any single job post. Normally this is done by passing the ID in the link `post.php?id=1`, then using that ID to query for the data.

Comment: @JimL, thanks for the quick reply. Your idea is perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Or use AJAX e.g. with jQuery $.ajax() you can request data from the server and replace the content, because you probably don't want to load the header and footer each time agan. Or even better AJAJ (asynchronous Javascript and JSON)

Comment: @callmeniko I won't take credit for that one, there are of course variations (to get pretty url's etc), but still this it is pretty much the way it's done